# How to check tags in lookup table

Tags: xslt

I have, this xml lookup table:

```
<lookup>
<Codes>
<code>123<code>
</Codes>
<Codes>
<code>321<code>
</Codes>
</lookup>
```

and document:

```
<document>
<header>
<remarks>test</remarks>
</header>
<Line>
<Line-Item>
<code>123</code>
</Line-Item>
<Line-Item>
<code>444</code>
</Line-Item>
<Line-Item>
<code>321</code>
</Line-Item>
</Line>
</document>
```

There is possible, to check document codes with lookup table codes, and if document code=lookup code, delete Line-Item from document.

answer should be:

```
<document>
<header>
<remarks>test</remarks>
</header>
<Line>
<Line-Item>
<code>444</code>
</Line-Item>
</Line>
</document>
```

I'm stuck on xsl:stylesheet version="1.0".
Best regards :)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete XSLT 1.0 solution that works correctly even in such edge cases when all `Line-Item/code` values are contained in the lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vCodes" select=
 "document('file:///c:/temp/LookupDelete.xml')/*/*/code"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "Line-Item[code
           = document('file:///c:/temp/LookupDelete.xml')
                  /*/*/code
           ]
 "/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Line[not(Line-Item/code
              [not(. = document('file:///c:/temp/LookupDelete.xml')
                               /*/*/code
                   )
              ]
           )
       ]
  "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<document>
    <header>
        <remarks>test</remarks>
    </header>
    <Line>
        <Line-Item>
            <code>123</code>
        </Line-Item>
        <Line-Item>
            <code>444</code>
        </Line-Item>
        <Line-Item>
            <code>321</code>
        </Line-Item>
    </Line>
</document>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<document>
   <header>
      <remarks>test</remarks>
   </header>
   <Line>
      <Line-Item>
         <code>444</code>
      </Line-Item>
   </Line>
</document>
```

**If the document is this**:

```
<document>
    <header>
        <remarks>test</remarks>
    </header>
    <Line>
        <Line-Item>
            <code>123</code>
        </Line-Item>
        <Line-Item>
            <code>321</code>
        </Line-Item>
        <Line-Item>
            <code>321</code>
        </Line-Item>
    </Line>
</document>
```

**then again the correct result is produced** (note that no `Line` element is output at all):

```
<document>
   <header>
      <remarks>test</remarks>
   </header>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I was searching something the same like you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- codes of items to exclude from external document -->
<xsl:variable name="lookup-table" select="document('lookup-table.xml')/lookup/Codes/code"/>

<!-- exclude Line-Items with codes from lookup table -->
<xsl:template match="Line-Item[ code = $lookup-table ]"/>

<!-- 
    exclude <Line> elements, 
    which contains only <Line-Item>'s which will be removed        
-->
<xsl:template match="Line[ not(Line-Item[ code != $lookup-table ]) ]"/>

<!-- copy all other items -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl;apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work in XSLT 1.0. Try it with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet produces the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:lookup="lookup">
    <lookup:lookup>
        <Codes>
            <code>123</code>
        </Codes>
        <Codes>
            <code>321</code>
        </Codes>
    </lookup:lookup>
    <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')/*/*/Codes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Line">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |
                 node()[not(self::Line-Item[code=$lookup/code])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the lookup table is included in the stylesheet. It could easily be included in a separate document if it's too large to include in the transformation.

Comment: @lwburk: I dont consider this answer correct, because when all `Line-Item/code` elements values are in the lookup table, it still produces a `Line` element.

Comment: @Dimitre - Fair enough, but I am trying to imagine a scenario where an empty `Line` element could possibly matter. Thoughts?

Comment: @lwburk: The fact is that from the three answers only yours generates this empty `Line` element. I know that even if we had a bigger number of answers and even if this ratio was 1000 : 1 you'd still say that there is value in producing an empty `Line`. But it is not the alleged "value" -- I am disappointed in finding that the majority of your recent answers all provide a hasty, "easiest to do without thinking" solutions and that you avoid to spend more time and to produce more meaningful and valuable solutions. I think that you have potential for much more and am expecting to see this.

Comment: @Dimitre - I'm not arguing that there's any value in producing an empty `Line`. I'm arguing that it couldn't possibly matter.

Comment: @lwburk: Producing clean output *really* matters. Can I guess that you thought of eliminating the empty `Line` element but found this too difficult or too time consuming?

Comment: @Dimitre - Never crossed my mind whether to include it or not. I'll ask for a third time: can you provide a scenario where having an empty `Line` element in the output would matter? I'm genuinely curious. I'll readily assume that I lack imagination.

Comment: @Dimitre - By the way, I appreciate the vote of confidence in my potential. Learning every day :)